# How do you dynamically get a particular method's name in a strongly typed way?

Tags: c#, vb.net, reflection

I'm a little unsure how to word the title to this question but I'm looking for a the shortest/aseist way in VB.NET (or C# but using VB.NET at the moment) to get the string value of a method's name dynamically given the method call.

For instance, I have a class like this:

```
Public Class Blah
    Public Sub Foo()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Now Foo is a strongly-typed cover for a dynamic setting and I have an event handler that will fire when the setting changes and return the string name of the setting that changed.

I'd like to be able to switch/select on this string and have a case based on the Foo() method.  To do this I need to able to get the string name of the Foo method from the method call itself (i.e. somehow GetMethodName(blahInstance.Foo())).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't have VB.NET handy at the moment, but in C#, I'm thinking this is the answer. Does this look approximately like what you're looking for?  If so, the VB.NET syntax should be relatively simple to work out:

```
     Blah blahInstance = new Blah();
     System.Action fooFunc = blahInstance.Foo;
     Console.WriteLine(fooFunc.Method.Name);
```

Comment: I've been using .NET since before beta 1, and I don't believe I've ever seen System.Delegate.Method used. Thanks for my "something new" for today.

Comment: OTOH, switching on the method name sounds like a _really_ bad idea, so maybe you should have kept the answer to yourself. ;-)

Comment: Well it seems better than switching on a string setting name because it is then strongly typed no?

Comment: Hmm, your example is great for my example but as I'm stuck with .NET 2.0 at the  moment I don't think I have access to Func so I can't deal with methods that have a return type this way (Action is for no return types).  Any ideas on if I'm missing anything?

Comment: @John Saunders I guess you are right - the proper way would probably be a new class type for each setting field but that seems like overkill.

Comment: You can create your own Func or Action delegates; there's nothing special about them.  For example "public delegate U Func<T,U>(T t);".

Comment: Oh right, thanks. For some reason I was imagining I'd have to make a seperate delegate type for each method.